# What happen when a X with a simple app is running and the app attempts to open a new window?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg

Using the following command to run firefox

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Start a program into an X server on the current VT.
function run-gui
{
    let _DISPLAY=$XDG_VTNR-1
    xinit -geometry =1920x1080+0+0 "$@" -- :$_DISPLAY vt$XDG_VTNR
}
```

with the following `.xinitrc`

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

setxkbmap -layout "us,bg(phonetic)" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
exec $3
```

nearly everything is fine. The problem is that any new mini-windows - like

- a right mouse click context menu
- the File, Edit ... menus on top
- basically anything except the expanding URL bar

appears for milliseconds and disappears.

The same behaviour is observed between all programs launched in the above-mentioned way.

One peculiarity is that *sometimes* this is not the case: the mini-windows do not disappear even after a minute. This happens rarely, only after a reboot, and quickly disappears.

Why is that happening? Can I fix it without installing a window manager? Actually **what** is happening?

Update:

> Display servers using the Wayland protocol are called compositors because they also act as compositing window managers.
> [source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wayland)

Seems like abolishing Xorg solves this problem as well. Yet Xorg is staying for a couple of decades more so my question of "what is happening" above stands tall.

Comment: You also need a window manager. Programs like firefox do not work without a wm, and show the same symptoms as you describe (they're the tip of the iceberg). I've once started to write a minimal wm just for being able to run ff or chromium in kiosk mode, but I never finished it. So find some lightweight wm.

Comment: And to add to that: Menus etc. are windows with special properties that are usually intercepted by the WM. Not sure if your `xinit` does start a WM, or if the applications your are using rely on the WM and are not made for a case where there is no WM.